# Recording Heap Allocations in 2018 Chrome Dev Tools?

Tags: google-chrome, memory-leaks, google-chrome-devtools, heap-memory

Google's documentation on how to do this is now out of date: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/memory-problems/allocation-profiler

The dev tools UI has changed since this was written (I'm using v66), and I can't figure out how to get to a heap allocation bar graph which looks like this:

[image]

Can anyone walk me through this? I've gone to Settings and checked `Record heap allocation stack traces` which I believe is one step that is required to do this. In the performance tab I've checked the `memory` box and have recorded some actions, but once that's done I get more of a line graph for heap, rather than a bar graph:

[image]

Halp?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Memory profilers are moved to Memory panel. The one you're looking for is called "Allocation instrumentation on timeline".

Comment: Bingo. Thank you!